# Give focus to an externally launched browser in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation, sikuli

I am opening a window based application in my desktop using Sikuli. After clicking on a button in that application, a browser is opened.

Can I get focus on that browser in Selenium? Can Webdriver detect an already opened browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to that is no. In order for Selenium Webdriver to control a browser it must be instantiated as WebDriver object creating a session ID, etc..

One possible solution might be to somehow intercept the URL that is generated by the desktop application and use it to launch a Webdriver instance.

Comment: How would someone "intercept the URL that is generated by the desktop application" without doing it manually?